# Selenide: can't import its methods

Tags: java, maven, selenide

I've created maven project with selenide 5.0.1
When i see code examples i see such code:

```
open("");
$(css);
$(xpath);
```

etc.

But i can't import Selenide methods
and i must write code in such way:

```
Selenide.open("");
Selenide.$(css);
```

etc.

trying import

```
import com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;
import com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$;
```

rises error in IDE

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You must use static import.

```
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.open;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.$;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to add dependencies in the pom.xml or gradle and download

[image]